# React useEffect redundant dependencies

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a useEffect which has two dependencies:

```
useEffect(() => {
   doSomething();
}, [currentTenant, currentProjects])
```

However, currentProjects is being set in a useEffect which has currentTenant as a dependency:

```
useEffect(() => {
   setCurrentProjects();
}, [currentTenant]);
```

`doSomething()` depends on both of these states, so I'm wondering if `doSomething()` will be running twice when `currentTenant` changes: once when `currentTenant` itself changes, and once when `currentProjects` (controlled by `currentTenant`) changes.

Is this redundant? What would be a better way of doing this? Maybe by removing `currentTenant` from the `doSomething()` useEffect.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: It depends on when you want doSomething() to run. If you want it to run after the render caused by change of `currentTenant` or change of `currentProjects` is done, then that is the place for it

Comment: I want `doSomething()` to run when `currentTenant` and `currentProjects` changes. But my original question, is will it run twice when `currentTenant` changes in this scenario.

Comment: It will run after every render, where currentTenant has changed. Its running has to do with renders primarily, and then values changing. In this case when **after a render** where currentTenant changed, it will run and yes after that when currentProjects changes again it will run again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making things error-prone and unneccessary complicated. In my experience, whenever ppl. try to be smart with `useEffect`, they just break it.

First, make sure that `currentTenant` and `currentProjects` are primitives - I guess that's not the case yet (exp. for something named `currentProjects`), so your dependencies won't work as expected anyway.

Second, if possible inline the code of `doSomething()` and `setCurrentProjects()` so it's easier to track which variables/dependencies you actually depend on. Exceptions are ofc if you've passed these methods to the component or you're using them at multiple places.

Third, don't rely on the execution order multiple `useEffect` hooks are called in. There's no guaranteed order in the documentation, and it wouldn't make much sense for async calls anyway. Make them independent of each other. So, don't assume redudancy where you can't be sure of it. Additionally, even if it worked as intended, it was premature optimization - the benefits are neglectable, but the code is way harder to understand.

Fourth, you're relying on the imagination that nothing will ever change in the component, and your future self as well as your colleagues will exactly know/remember about your dependency considerations. Or you've got to comment it with a lengthy explanation in there, making thinkgs even more complicated.

In general, try to be as plain and expressive as possible with `useEffect` dependencies. There's not much magic to them, but many ppl. screw them up at times nevertheless (me included). And it happens when you deviate from that "just list all primitives you're using" rule most of the times.

Comment: Hi @NotX, thanks for the answer. I'm still wondering if this kind of arrangement will cause `doSomething()` to be run twice, since one of its dependencies depends on the other dependency.

currentProjects isn't a primitive and never will be, it's a useState array of objects. Also, I didn't do this useEffect chain on purpose, that's just how it ended up, I only noticed it today. 

Lastly, I sometimes have to take one of the primitives I'm using out of the dependency array, because I just don't want the useEffect to run when that changes, since I'm trying to limit how many times it runs.

Comment: @Cjmaret it might run twice, and this is probably totally fine. if `currentProjects` is not primitive, `useEffect` will run even more often (on any virtual rerendering in the worst case). Use [this](https://github.com/kentcdodds/use-deep-compare-effect) library if it can't be helped. It's hard to give any details without knowing your code, but removing primitives to avoid it to be run too often sounds like a really unreliable approach and could probably achieved in another way. Maybe you can merge both `useEffect()` calls instead? Hard to give advice without knowing `doSomething()`.